# get data from database in combobox in gwt

Tags: json, gwt, combobox

I have created a registration module in GWT with 5 fields that I had done successfully but now I want to get 3 security question form the user while registration so in that security question will will there in database and I have to get those question in security question combo box but I am not getting proper solution for that.and I have to use json .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your struggle with more than one thing. Combo box is a selection box. Do you offer predefined questions or should the user be able to enter an arbitrary question? How should the user enter the answer to that question? Where do have to store the data? Is there already a server side database? Do you have a database schema?

Comment: @Peter - those questions are already stored in db so for it there is 1 table with fieIds quesId and question . And while selecting those ques its id will be stored in another table which will have fields like userid ,quesId ,answer,and a primary key column. So my question was I want those question on my registration page combobox and i am using json gwt and hibernate criteria to select those questions.

Comment: Please be so kind and tell us, what you have tried so far and what frameworks aso. you are using. Please, read through "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" in order to understand how a problem should be explained and to get an answer more likely.

Comment: I want to create a registration form on which user will choose 3 security question while registration for the case of forgot password so these security question are already in database  I want to load these questions in my combo box(sencha gwt combo box) that set . In other words I want to read the security questions from server to client when the registration page is loaded . And in this application I am using json . I hope my question is clear now.